# Spring Data (Hibernate) dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a repository like this

```
@Repository
public interface LeadRequestRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<LeadRequest, UUID> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM lead_request WHERE product IN :products AND current_status in :status", nativeQuery = true)
    List<LeadRequest> findLeadRequests(@Param("products") List<String> products, @Param("status") List<String> status);

}
```

In this query, the status can be null or empty list.
In such case, the query must returns all status (NEW, APPROVED, REJECTED, etc). In other words, the query must become `SELECT * FROM lead_request WHERE product IN :products` and no `status` clause.
I'm also confused because I use `IN` clause, so I can't use JPA Example API

How can I achieve this using hibernate and jpa?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. You would have two JPQL/native queries and based on null condition you would call one or the other query.
2. Better option is to use JPA criterial queries. Spring Data JPA provides abstraction for JPA criteria queries called `Specifications`. Take a look into [Spring Data JPA docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#specifications)